# How to rename a key in a hash if it exists

Tags: ruby, hashmap, hashtable

I have the following hash:

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  answer: '42'
}
```

How can I elegantly rename the key `:foo` to a new key `:test`? If the hash entry for `:foo` does not exist, the hash should not be altered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
a[:test] = a.delete(:foo) if a.key?(:foo)
```